# Modifying member variable in one thread and reading in a different thread

Tags: c++, pthreads

I have two member variables.

```
class MessageQueues {
    ....
    char* m_InputBuffer;
    uint32_t m_InputBufferSize;
    ....
};
```

I am updating them in a function in the current thread and see with the debugger even, that the member variables are updated. But in the other function, running in a separate thread, the member variables contain garbage.

So, I have a function, which is reading two values and writing them to the two member variables and triggering the other thread when done.

```
ErrorCode MessageQueue::handleIncomingMessage(char receiveBuffer[], const uint32_t bufferSize) {
    ES_TRC3("started");
    ErrorCode errorCode = ES_SUCCESS;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexMsgQueueIncoming);
    m_InputBuffer = receiveBuffer;
    m_InputBufferSize = bufferSize;
    ES_TRC3("triggering and unlocking");
    pthread_cond_signal(&msgQueueCondition);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexMsgQueueIncoming);
    ES_TRC3("triggered and unlocked");
    return errorCode;
}
```

Then in a 2nd member function, which is running in a separate thread indefinitely and waiting for messages,

```
ErrorCode MessageQueue::runReceiver(void) {
    ES_TRC3("started");
    ErrorCode errorCode = ES_SUCCESS;
    while(true)
    {
        ES_TRC3("waiting for input messages");
        pthread_cond_wait(&msgQueueCondition, &mutexMsgQueueIncoming);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexMsgQueueIncoming);
        ES_TRC3("will parse message");
        if (strlen(m_InputBuffer) > 0UL) {
            if ((errorCode = m_MsgProtocol->parseMessage(m_InputBuffer, m_InputBufferSize)) != ES_SUCCESS)
            {
                ES_TRC1("failed to parseMessage, error:%d", errorCode);
            }
        }
        ES_TRC3("message parsed");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexMsgQueueIncoming);
    }
    return errorCode;
}
```

With the debugger (and with the log messages), I can see that the update of the variables and the triggering happens in the correct order. So I can't figure out why then in the 2nd function, the member variables don't appear to contain the correct values. I read something about "volatile" somewhere. But don't really think, that is the right answer. Am I doing something wrong here?

**UPDATE:**
The mutexes are outside the class but in the same source file, intialized at the top like this.

```
pthread_mutex_t mutexMsgQueueIncoming       = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t msgQueueCondition            = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
```

Actually, it is strange. When, I run the program without a debugger, it seems the mutex cannot be locked in the runReceiver() function. With the debugger, the mutex is locked but the member variables contain garbage. Ok, I think I should investigate this.

Comment: Where are you locking in first block of code? There is unlocking but withiout a locking?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @JoeyMallone is there a possibility that mutexMsgQueueIncoming is different in both threads? Maybe some class copy constructor having different initialized mutexes? Have you tried to access class instance through its pointer, from both threads, instead of passing it by value? Also what if there is a spurious wake up in second block? How does it re-wait?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik, ok, let me investigate this a little. Thanks for the ideas/tips.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik, actually, my first comment was wrong. After adding the lock, before the member variable update, the behavior is different. I can now, not unlock the mutex in the runReceiver() function. I will update the code in the question now.

Regarding, copy constructors, the mutex is a global outside the class (not a member of the class).

Regarding spurious wake and re-wake, I would need to google a bit about that first.

I can say one thing, I lock or unlock the said mutex in only those lines which I am showing here.

Comment: I recommend std::thread instead of pthreads.

Comment: @n.m. I'd prefer std::thread also. But I am stuck here in a gcc compiler version 4.4.5-8. I cannot use C++11 stuff.

Comment: Use boost::thread then.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I'd wish, I had those kinds of liberties to pick and choose. :P

Comment: @Joey Maybe one day!

Comment: @AlanBirtles, I finally got around to making a small compact compilable example. https://github.com/junaidnaseer/pthreadsWithClass/blob/master/main.cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of errors here:

1. Waiting on the condition variable must be done when the mutex is locked. [pthread_cond_wait](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_timedwait.html) documentation is a must read.
2. Condition variable [spurious wake-ups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup) must be handled by a `while` loop.

Fixes:

```
class MessageQueues {
    ....
    char* m_InputBuffer;
    uint32_t m_InputBufferSize;
    uint32_t m_WriteGeneration = 0; // <--- a fix.
    uint32_t m_ReadGeneration = 0;  // <--- a fix.
    ....
};

ErrorCode MessageQueue::handleIncomingMessage(char receiveBuffer[], const uint32_t bufferSize) {
    ES_TRC3("started");
    ErrorCode errorCode = ES_SUCCESS;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexMsgQueueIncoming);
    m_InputBuffer = receiveBuffer;
    m_InputBufferSize = bufferSize;
    ++m_WriteGeneration; // <--- a fix.
    ES_TRC3("triggering and unlocking");
    pthread_cond_signal(&msgQueueCondition);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexMsgQueueIncoming);
    ES_TRC3("triggered and unlocked");
    return errorCode;
}

ErrorCode MessageQueue::runReceiver(void) {
    ES_TRC3("started");
    ErrorCode errorCode = ES_SUCCESS;
    while(true)
    {
        ES_TRC3("waiting for input messages");
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexMsgQueueIncoming);  // <--- a fix.
        while(m_ReadGeneration == m_WriteGeneration) // <--- a fix.
            pthread_cond_wait(&msgQueueCondition, &mutexMsgQueueIncoming); // <--- a fix.
        m_ReadGeneration = m_WriteGeneration; // <--- a fix.
        ES_TRC3("will parse message");
        if (strlen(m_InputBuffer) > 0UL) {
            if ((errorCode = m_MsgProtocol->parseMessage(m_InputBuffer, m_InputBufferSize)) != ES_SUCCESS)
            {
                ES_TRC1("failed to parseMessage, error:%d", errorCode);
            }
        }
        ES_TRC3("message parsed");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexMsgQueueIncoming);
    }
    return errorCode;
}
```

Note that if `handleIncomingMessage` is called twice when `runReceiver` unlocked the mutex this code loses the message. You probably need a message queue here, rather than storing the last message (i.e. you have a queue of size 1 which drops old elements on overflow).

The code also needs to check error codes returned by pthread functions. This is rather tedious, better use C++11 `std::mutex`, `std::condition_variable`, `std::unique_lock` that do the checks for you. In C++98 you can use `boost` equivalents.

Comment: ouch thanks. I had misunderstood on how to use, pthread_cond_wait() then. Let me test this after lunch. Probably that was the mistake. I should familiarize myself more with the pthread library. Thanks.

p.s. I cannot use C++11. I cannot use Boost. I am stuck in 1998. :P

Comment: @JoeyMallone In 1998 you can use Boost.

Comment: oh my goodness! :O Then I am even not in 1998! I cannot use Boost. Not my choice. It is not my choice.

Comment: @JoeyMallone Make thin wrappers over pthread primitives then that do error checking for you.